# can't figure out why my svg gradients won't show in Firefox when ran on my computer

Tags: node.js, angular, svg, angular-cli

I'm using Node 8.9.1, NPM 5.8.1 and Angular 5 with CLI 1.6.7.  I have several elements that use the same color gradient with different parameters like in the picture below.

[image: svg elements using same color gradient]

To minimize the amount of code in the document I define the colors in one gradient then reference it with an `href` in the other gradients like so

```
<radialGradient id="border_clr_prim_t">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
    <stop  offset="0.6007" style="stop-color:#DBE2E8"/>
    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#C0CDD8"/>
</radialGradient>

<radialGradient
    id="border_clr_t01"
    href="#border_clr_prim_t"
    cx="141.8091" cy="193.6915" r="9.4921"
    gradientTransform="matrix(-4.764515e-02 0.9989 -0.6589 -3.142960e-02 276.1911 58.1311)"
    gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
</radialGradient>

<path id="lp_01"
    style="fill:url(#border_clr_t01);"
    d="M148.4,196.1l-0.5-4.9c-1.3,0.1-2.6,0.2-4,0.2c-2.5,0-5.1-0.3-7.5-0.8l-1,4.8l-0.1,0.3c2.8,0.6,5.7,0.9,8.6,0.9c1.5,0,3-0.1,4.5-0.2L148.4,196.1z"
/>
```

I use `<symbol>`s to organize my graphic into layers so I can do things with them individually in the HTML.  If you [view this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/yOKnW1UOsSTlnKSNlgD9?p=preview) you'll see I have 3 boxes titled *function embedded*, *src path* and *plain svg*.  In Chrome you'll notice the *src path* is empty, which is expected, while in Firefox all 3 are visible, which is also expected.  My problem is when running the same code in my app the elements using gradients like the example above doesn't render in Firefox.  I originally made the plunkr as a minimal verifiable example to ask why the *function embedded* one won't render just to discover that it actually does in the plunkr.

I went a step farther and made both a plunker and stackblitz demo out of my graphic and they both show up perfectly fine in Firefox.  I've been over my code and can't figure out what could be different on plunker and stackblitz other than the inner workings.  Due to a bug in Chrome I can't just `src` to it as one normally would, I need to use the function to embed it as well as the `svg4everybody` plugin.  Does anybody have any clue as to what could be causing this to happen on my machine?

Comment: Have you put the gradients in something which is display:none? If that's not the right guess we'll need a [mcve]

Comment: I use `visibility: hidden;` in my code, I came across that problem as well.